# Fastest way to unpack bits (sub-byte) numbers from file

Tags: python, file, binary, bit

Given a file with resolution-compressed binary data, I would like to convert the sub-byte bits into their integer representations in python. By this I mean I need to interpret `n` bits from a file as an integer.

Currently I am reading the file into `bitarray` objects, and am converting subsets of the objects into integers. The process works but is fairly slow and cumbersome. Is there a better way to do this, perhaps with the `struct` module?

```
import bitarray

bits = bitarray.bitarray()
with open('/dir/to/any/file.dat','r') as f:
    bits.fromfile(f,2) # read 2 bytes into the bitarray

    ## bits 0:4 represent a field
    field1 = int(bits[0:4].to01(), 2)  # Converts to a string of 0s and 1s, then int()s the string

    ## bits 5:7 represent a field
    field2 = int(bits[4:7].to01(), 2)

    ## bits 8:16 represent a field
    field3 = int(bits[7:16].to01(), 2)

print """All bits: {bits}\n\tfield1: {b1}={field1}\n\tfield2: {b2}={field2}\n\tfield3: {b3}={field3}""".format(
        bits=bits, b1=bits[0:4].to01(), field1=field1, 
        b2=bits[4:7].to01(), field2=field2,
        b3=bits[7:16].to01(), field3=field3)
```

Outputs:

```
All bits: bitarray('0000100110000000')
    field1: 0000=0
    field2: 100=4
    field3: 110000000=384
```

Comment: Do the field sizes repeat as you go through the file, or are they completely random? Do they cross byte boundaries?

Comment: 1. Fields do cross byte boundaries. 2. Fields do repeat, but there is an unknown size chunk that must be read dynamically. I.E. in my example, you can say that `field3` tells me how big `field4` needs to be. Then the file repeats `field1`, `field2` etc.

Comment: is the size of field4 in bytes or bits? Must it all fit in an integer?

Comment: `field4` is in bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for your specific case:

```
#bitmasks of fields 1-3, they fit in 2 bytes
FIELD1 = 0b1111000000000000 # first 4 bits
FIELD2 = 0b0000111000000000 # next 3 bits
FIELD3 = 0b0000000111111111 # last 9 bits

def bytes_to_int(num):  #convert bytes object to an int
    res = 0
    num = num[::-1]  # reverse the bytes
    for i in range(len(num)):
        res += num[i] * (256**i)
    return res

def get_fields(f):
    chunk = bytes_to_int(f.read(2))  # read 2 bytes, f1-f3, convert to int
    f1 = (chunk & FIELD1) >> 12  # get each field with its bitmask
    f2 = (chunk & FIELD2) >> 9
    f3 = chunk & FIELD3
    f4 = f.read(f3)  # field4 as a bytes object

    return f1, f2, f3, f4

file = open('file.dat','rb')

#using your sample data
print(get_fields(file))  # returns 0, 4, 384, field4 as a bytes obj

file.close()
```

Comment: Good mention for `int.from_bytes`. Unfortunately I'm running 2.7. This is what I'm looking for though

Comment: @zachd1_618 ok...I can correct that...are you reading the file as text or in the raw bytes format? If its just 1s and 0s as text, then int(n,2) can do the conversion. Also is it correct to say that since field4 is in bytes and doesnt cross byte boundaries, then only fields 1-3 are at the sub-byte level and they all fit in 2 bytes?

Comment: I am reading the file in raw bytes. Like your example with `file.read(num_bytes)`. And yes it is correct to say that the unknown size `field4` is in whole bytes and does not cross byte boundaries.

Comment: @zachd1_618 this should work for your specific case in python 2.

Comment: great formulation! The bitwise operators was what I was missing. I adapted the method for my scenario (have to build the `FIELD` masks dynamically) and got about an order of magnitude improvement over  using `bitarrary` objects. Very nice.

Answer (score 4):

If you are ok with using someone's module, it looks like the bitstring module has good representation and manipulation of bits: http://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/index.html

For instance, if you know the size of your fields you could use format strings:
http://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/reading.html#reading-using-format-strings

```
import bitstring
bitstream = bitstring.ConstBitStream(filename='testfile.bin')
field1, field2, field3 = bitstream.readlist('int:4, int:3, int:9')
```

If you didn't know your fields sizes you could read in all the bits and then use slicing to extract all your fields: http://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/slicing.html

```
import bitstring
bitstream = bitstring.ConstBitStream(filename='testfile.bin')
bits = bitstring.BitArray(bitstream)
field1 = bits[0:4].int
field2 = bits[4:7].int
field3 = bits[7:16].int
```

Just a thought, you probably already found this module.

Comment: Oh and if you want to use unsigned instead of signed use uint